# Is it possible to move around the <audio> control panel?

Tags: html, css

I'm using HTML5, and CSS3.

I just learned about the  tag. However, whenever I use it on a page, the control box is always positioned on the far left. I have tried a few things to move it, to no avail.

> `<audio control loop autoplay><source src="music.mp3"></audio>`

Comment: Do you have an example of on website to show what you mean by far left? Do you mean on the left side of the page? Or Left side of the position you place it?

Comment: I mean, it is positioned on the very far left of the page, in the center. I can't seem to move it. I find it very intriguing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these situations, I typically wrap the element in a div (or some other element that can be more straightforwardly styled), and this works well.

So you could do something like this (if you wanted, say, to center the music control and make it 500px wide - you can, of course, do any number of other style manuevers):

```
<div style="width:500px; margin:auto; position:relative;">
    <audio controls style="width:100%;">
       <source src="Rococo.MP3">This browser does not support the audio tag
    </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. Also, I wasn't aware that the <audio> tags had a 'style' declaration? Is this true? Or for some reason, has placing it in a div tag, added the potential to it's code, and added features that the vanilla html5 didn't have before?

Comment: @Garlotch - it does indeed! What's interesting is that I was working on a situation a year ago where I was trying to style an <audio> tag in a very simple way, and **nothing** was working. I did some research, and found a blog post where the author suggested wrapping the <audio> element in a <div> (he was doing this so that his <audio> would resize successfully on mobile screens). So that's where I got the idea from (and, alas, I can't find that blog now). While answering your question, though, I tried styling <audio> again and this time it worked. So maybe browser support is better now.